# JDBC connection in JSP :java.lang.RuntimePermission accessClassInPackage.sun.jdbc.odbc

Tags: java, sql-server, jsp, web-applications, jdbc

Here i am trying to connect with Database through `JDBC`.

Here is my code and ended up with the below exception.

```
<%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import ="javax.sql.*" %>


<%
  Connection con = null;
  String url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.0.123:4070/";
  String db = "RUTHER_FORD";
  String driver = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
  String userName ="RUTHER";
  String password="SORRY_CONFIDENTIAL";

  int sumcount=0;
  Statement st;
  try{
      Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
      con = DriverManager.getConnection(url+db,userName,password);
      String query = "select * from user_master";
      st = con.createStatement();
      ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
%>
<%
      while(rs.next()){
%>

        <%System.out.println(rs.getString(1));%>
        <%System.out.println(rs.getString(2));%>

<%
      }
%>
<%
  }
  catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
%>

<html>

.
.
.
.
```

//Below is the exception facing ,when i am dispatching the page

```
 java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission accessClassInPackage.sun.jdbc.odbc)
        at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:323)
        at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:546)
        at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(DevAppServerFactory.java:166)
        at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPackageAccess(SecurityManager.java:1512)
```

Below I saw one more exception

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission C:\Windows\TEMP read)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:323)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:546)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(DevAppServerFactory.java:166)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(SecurityManager.java:871)
    at java.io.File.isDirectory(File.java:752)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC2.unpackProperties(ConnectionJDBC2.java:1253)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC2.<init>(ConnectionJDBC2.java:280)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC3.<init>(ConnectionJDBC3.java:50)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:184)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
    at org.apache.jsp.mmrda_005fsupplierportal.index_002dleft_002dcontainer_jsp._jspService(index_002dleft_002dcontainer_jsp.java:71)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
P.S I added jtdc.1.2.5 jar to my `class path`.
```

What i am missing ??any suggetions on this ?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: check this up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967256/database-connection-problem-with-ms-sql-database-jdbc-odbc-driver-from-jsp?rq=1

Comment: You really really shouldn't have database related code in a jsp (or use scriptlets at all). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create server.policy file and put file in the place where your java files are.
Add following line in the file and save. Try this one and tell us  if it works

```
grant {
permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```